# Codeigniter - form error display underneath the input field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter-3

I am trying to display a form error underneath the input fields but after I click the submit button it will redirect to another page...

Here's my code page controller

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Pages extends CI_Controller{

        public function view($page = 'home'){
            if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                show_404();
            }
            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        }

        public function login(){
            echo $this->input->POST('username');
        }

        public function registercheck(){

            echo $this->input->POST('username');
            echo $this->input->POST('pwd');
            echo $this->input->POST('pwd2');
            echo $this->input->POST('fname');
            echo $this->input->POST('position');
            echo $this->input->POST('contactnumber');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'USERNAME', 'required|max_lenght[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pwd', 'USERNAME', 'required|max_lenght[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pwd2', 'UPPERCASE', 'required|max_lenght[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'USERNAME', 'required|max_lenght[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('position', 'USERNAME', 'required|max_lenght[20]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contactnumber', 'USERNAME', 'required|max_lenght[20]');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
                $this->load->view('pages/register');
            } else{
                echo 'register ok';
            }                   
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is my views/pages/register.php

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/registercheck" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" >
    <?php if (form_error('username')) { ?>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('username');  ?> </span>
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" >
    <?php  if (form_error('username')) { ?>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('username');  ?> </span>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Please help me.. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you solved your issue, please mark one of the answers as accepted and upvote. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You are in the right direction. But to achieve the desire functionality, you should do as so:

The form and the input validation should be in the same **page** (controller). In your example, both should be in `register.php`.

This basic pseudo code should do the trick:

```
On register page controller:
    If method == get:
        Display register form.
    If method == post:
        Check the form data:
        If errors exists:
            display register page with error.
        else:
            redirect to ....
```

Good Luck!